# Is it "ok" to add columns to the information schema metadata table in a Postgres database?

Tags: database, postgresql, security, web, html

By "ok" I mean a safe, practical, generally acceptable way to go about achieving the following:

I am constructing a web tool in which every entry in a Postgres table and their fields are viewable by users. The entire table is visible, essentially. Users also have access to edit the fields of entries they create. In addition, administrators should have access to define certain aspects of each field, so users understand what they should enter as a value. For instance, the "description" of the field "name" would be "Enter your name."

So, would it be ok to add a "description" field to the information_schema.columns table in my Postgres database which administrators will have web access to edit, or is this a poor route to take? If it is poor, what would be an acceptable alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information schema consists of a set of views, and is therefore not a physical table that can be edited. Read the first paragraph of the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/information-schema.html). You should simply add a column 'description' to each table that only admins can update.